# Pointer not initializing with a struct as a parameter. Access violation writing location 0x00000010.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, struct

The struct looks like this:

```
template <class Node_entry>
Node<Node_entry>::Node(Node_entry item, Node *add_on)
{
    entry = item;
    next = add_on;
}
```

And the *new_rear pointer does not get initialized, but &item is filled with user input.

```
   Error_code Extended_queue::append(const Queue_entry &item) {
        Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear = new Node<Queue_entry>(item);
        if(new_rear = 0)
            return overflow;
        if(rear = 0){
            front = new_rear;
            rear = new_rear;
        }
        else {
            rear->next = new_rear;
            rear = new_rear;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

In the locals in VS2010 this and new_rear are both (!) in the next and the entry, the item is good. What am I doing to get this?

> "Access violation writing location 0x00000010."

Comment: Turn. On. Warnings. Always. This is why we have them. Also, `new_rear` will never be 0 anyway.

Comment: It could, if you run out of memory and don't use exceptions to trap that case.

Comment: Just as a quick extra note, VC10 supports C++0x's nullptr, so you should use that instead of the old 0.

Comment: @Ebo: No, it will never be zero. The exception will propagate and `new_rear` will have never existed. That first `if` statement will **never** be entered on a compliant compiler. (Fixed with `==`, that is.)

Comment: There are lots of platforms that don't throw an exception if an allocation fails.

Comment: @Ebo: Not in C++. What do platforms have anything to do with a language standard? Do you mean compiler? I think the last compiler that returned 0 instead of throw was VC6, so long ago.

Comment: The Xbox 360 environment doesn't do that, for example. Also, some projects disable exception handling.

Comment: @Ebo: So you mean the compiler for XBox 360? Then it's non-compliant. (Probably because of your next point?) A project that disables exceptions is no longer working in standard C++. This code and question is about standard C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you meant to say `if (new_rear == 0)`, not `if (new_rear = 0)`? Your compiler should have given you a warning.

EDIT: In case you are wondering why it crashes - well, you're assigning 0 to the pointers, which also makes the conditions evaluate to zero, so you end up in the else block with "rear" just freshly assigned to 0, so "rear->next" ends up writing to 0x10.

Btw, this is why I always compile with the highest warning level, and warnings treated as errors. Warnings are your friends.

Comment: Wow... I didn't even notice. How do I turn on the warnings in VC2010? I usually use DEVCPP.

Comment: Ugh yeah. Depending on your setup, you could compile them separately, and on some compilers you could temporarily turn off the warnings when you include the headers via pragmas. But sloppily written libraries are the devil.

Comment: In the properties of your project. There's a setting for the warning level (1-4), and an option to treat warnings as errors.